# Where to generate panoramas of the far north?

Tags: images

[HeyWhatsThat](https://www.heywhatsthat.com/) is a great service to see panoramas of a lot of the Earth's surface, but when I try to generate one from Northern Norway I get the following error message:

> Invalid latitude. We currently cover latitude 60N to 54S and most of Alaska.

Is there some way to work around that or is it a fundamental issue with the site?

Comment: I get the same error message. I think it's because of a fundamental issue with the site as you stated. Gonna e-mail them and ask why it's like that later

Answer (score 1):

It is fundamental. See **[What data do you use?](http://www.heywhatsthat.com/faq.html#main)**:

> We use two sets of data to generate these results. First, we use a digital elevation model, which is the height of the surface of the Earth above sea level at a network of points. In this case we're using the SRTM data generated by the February 2000 Space Shuttle mission. It comprises elevations determined roughly every 100 feet north-south and east-west for the US and every 300 feet elsewhere, covering latitude 60°N to 54°S. For more information, see the NASA Jet Propulsion Laboratory and USGS Shuttle Radar Topography Mission pages.